# Support different screen sizes dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, screen-size

I have an app that draws circle on a custom view and their radiuses have hard-coded values. however, it doesn't look good on devices with lower screen sizes as the circles appear bigger and also their initial coordinates are hard coded as well, so because the circle are bouncing, they tend to get out of the screen.

exemple: Circle 1 `x = 50, y = 600 r = 200`, Circle 2 `x = 550, y= 130, r = 150` etc.

How can I define their radiuses and initial positions so that they can fit on all screen sizes?

Comment: Make you own screen unit that is proportional to the device. For example, your screen is always "1000" wide. If the device is say, 720px wide, then each px of the screen is equal to 1000/720. With this base constant you can place anything on the screen, and it will look the same, no matter the device. Height is another issue :]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is that a good way to do such things? And what do you mean by heigh is an issue

Comment: Your layout design will need to have a flexible height as pretty much each device has a different height. In the past I have defined a width and height (aspect ratio) and created a buffer (or padding) for which ever size does not fit cleanly on the screen so that I can keep the aspect ratio of my layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use **SDP - a scalable size unit** library for supporting different screens.

An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.
Here is the [LINK](https://github.com/intuit/sdp#sdp---a-scalable-size-unit)

Comment: Tried this, but doesn't scale proberly< Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: @Krul what happen when you set the size using this library?